# hook_field_formatter_view doesn't get called

Tags: 7, entities

I'm kind of new to this formatter, widget system, so i hope you can help me out.
I'm trying to add a new widget to field type list_text, so i have added a info hook like this

```
function market_field_widget_info() {
  return array(
    'product_list' => array(
    'label' => t('Product List'),
    'field types' => array('list_text'),
    'settings' => array('size' => 40),
    'behaviors' => array(
      'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
    ),
  ),
);
```

And to my widget i have added a widget form hook like this

```
function market_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {

  if ($instance['widget']['type'] == 'product_list' && arg(0) == 'node' ) {

  $node = node_load(arg(1));

  $options = array();
  foreach($node->field_products['und'] as $item ) {
    $entity = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($item['value']));
    $options[$item['value']] = $entity[$item['value']]->field_title['und'][0]['value'];
  }

  $element['product'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Vare'),
    '#options' => $options,
  ); 
return $element;
}
```

And this works great, i get the information into the selector that i want, but when it is posted nothing is displayed, so i added a view to it

```
function market_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();

  switch ($display['type']) {
    // This formatter simply outputs the field as text and with a color.
    case 'default_list':
      foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        $element[$delta]['#markup'] = "TEST";
      }
      break;
  }

  return $element;
}
```

But still nothing, am i missing something here? I have tried putting in a die, but its like the view hook is never called, hope you can help.

Best regards

Comment: Have you cleared Drupal's cache since adding the new hook?

Comment: Many many times

Comment: Since you don't say what you actually want to do, I want to point out that a widget is used for controlling _input_ to a field, while a formatter controls _output_ from a field. You may not need both.

Comment: Well actually i just wanted to set the values in the select list, depending on users content in the node. so i thought i could just add a new widget with the values, which i could, but it doesn't show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for [`hook_field_formatter_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7) to be called you also need to implement [`hook_field_formatter_info`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7), to let the field system know about your custom formatter.

There's a good article called [Creating new field formatters in Drupal 7](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/creating-new-field-formatters-drupal-7) that has a step by step guide.